# Why is foreground semi-transparent when opacity is set to 1.0, in VSE?

Tags: transparency

Using Blender VSE 2.83, windows 10. Codec H.264, output quality high, fps=30, 1920 x 1080 input and output. Container Mpeg4. I rendered mp4 to a png sequence, to overlay a background. When I add the sequence to the sequencer, it shows the png sequence as semi-transparent, even though I have opacity set at 1.0. What have I done wrong? The window is supposed to be behind me.[image]

Comment: You forgot to attach your screenshot. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIFs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: since the VSE Editor has a lot of settings/possibilies it might be a good idea to upload your blend file so we can check it out. https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: if you don't want your question be closed again you should add more information to your question. e.g. screenshots which help us (who can answer). and not just a 2cmx2cm pic, but a pic, where we can see something. or better a blend file so we can check it out. With questions like these you are wasting your own time (because it will be closed) and ours...